# ¿Qué alternativa hay a window.location.href que copie la url original y no la enmascarada?

Tags: javascript, script, url

Les cuento, he agregado un [script](https://github.com/jokenox/bloggerjs/blob/master/README.md) que enmascara las urls predeterminadas en las entradas del blog de blogger, para darle un diseño más limpio, ya que muestran la fecha y terminan con la extensión html. Si bien el script redirecciona, lo mejor es utilizar la url original para que se aligere la carga. Así que agregue el siguiente botón al final para que solo presionen y se copie la url pero copia la url enmascarada, el script utiliza la propiedad [window.location.href](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp). ¿Existe una propiedad que solucione esto?

La otra es, Blogger [tiene un botón](https://activismoeficazea.blogspot.com/) de copiar el enlace permanente de entrada, la cuestión es que para verlo tienen que darle en el enlace compartir, y ni idea de cómo extraerlo de allí. Ellos utilizan una serie de [etiquetas](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en), entre ellas la data:post.url que contiene la href permanente, pero no encuentro información de cómo implementarlo. Espero alguno de ustedes tengan una solución que seguro a otros les será de ayuda también. Gracias.

```js
//<![CDATA[
var boton = document.getElementById('getlink');
boton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if(boton.id == 'getlink'){
var aux = document.createElement('input');
aux.setAttribute('value', window.location.href.split('?')[0].split('#')[0]);
document.body.appendChild(aux);
aux.select();
try {
document.execCommand('copy');
var aviso = document.createElement('div');
aviso.setAttribute('id', 'aviso');
aviso.style.cssText = 'position:fixed; z-index: 9999999; top: 20%;left:50%;margin-left: -70px;padding: 10px; background: #000000;opacity: 0.80;border-radius: 8px;color: white;';
aviso.innerHTML = 'URL copiada al portapapeles';
document.body.appendChild(aviso);
document.load = setTimeout('document.body.removeChild(aviso)', 2200);
document.load = setTimeout('boton.id = "getlink"',2500);
boton.id = '';
} catch (e) {
alert('Tu navegador no soporta la función de copiar. Intenta con el botón de compartir.');
}
document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
});
//]]>
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class='copi' id='getlink' href='javascript:void();' style="float:left;margin-left:50%"><span class='fa-stack' style='color: #1C1C1C;'><i class='far fa-circle fa-stack-2x'></i><i class="fas fa-link fa-lg fa-stack-1x"></i></span></a>
```

Comment: podes probar con `document.URL`

Comment: Tiene una función similar, devuelve la url enmascarada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se de ninguna propiedad para solucionar esto, pero se me ocurre un "truco". Como la modificación de la url se hace mediante un script, podrías meter antes un script que coja la url (aun sin enmascarar) y la almacene en una variable que luego uses para pintar el enlace. Algo así:

```
<script>
  var urlOriginal=window.location.href;
</script>
```

y luego en el script que has subido y utilizas para crear el botón con la url deberías de cambiar esta linea:

```
aux.setAttribute('value', window.location.href.split('?')[0].split('#')[0]);
```

Por esta otra:

```
aux.setAttribute('value', urlOriginal);
//En el código original haces una serie de splits, como no se que url tienes no se si sera necesario.
```

Otra cosa que se me ocurre pero que no he podido probar es usar `window.location.hostname` y `window.location.pathname` que te devuelven el dominio y el path que debería estar sin enmascarar. Luego los juntas y debería de darte la url absoluta (digo debería porque viendo el comportamiento de href no me extrañaría que no funcionase...):

```
var urlOriginal= window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: pathname devuelve la url enmascarada. Lastimosamente no tengo el conocimiento para hacer que el script aloje la url predeterminada y luego la tire.

Comment: He editado la respuesta un poco. Bastaría con poner el primer script que he puesto en el <head>, antes del script de bloggerJS (de esta forma ya tendrías guardada la url sin mascara en la variable `urlOriginal`). Y luego realizar el cambio que te indico en el código que has subido.

Comment: Genial. Gracias por explicar. A funcionado.